# Making a vector that contains Python string in Cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, cython

Is there a way to make a Cython vector store a Python string? because when i do this:

```
cdef vector[str] vectStr
```

It gives an error when i try to compile it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do mean a C++ vector (I'm not sure what else it could mean): no you can't. Python strings end up being represented as `PyObject*`, and these need careful handling to ensure the reference count is correct. A C++ `vector<PyObject*>` is not set up to do this reference counting and so would end up leaking the memory.

Practically, to make it work you'd have to write a C++ wrapper to hold the pointers and do the reference counting. This is getting beyond the scope of what you can do purely in Cython.

Your best option would be to wrap a C++ vector of C++ strings. Cython can automatically convert these from Python strings (at the cost of a copying operation) so the code is very easy to write:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef vector[string] x = ['hello', 'aaaaa']  # autoconversion from list of strings to vector
```

---

I suspect you may be trying to do this as a way of approximating a "typed list of strings" (which you can't represent directly in Cython). The cost of copying to and from the C++ datatypes makes this pointless in most cases - if you have to work with pure Python types such as `list` then just work with the Python types - don't invent complicated typing schemes to force Cython to do things that aren't really supported.

Comment: Can i do `stringVect.push_back('Hi')` ?

Comment: Yes - this will create a `std::string` copy of 'Hi'.

Comment: How about object from a cdef class?

Comment: No. Again a `PyObject*` and therefore needs reference counting so incompatible with C++ vectors.

Comment: An example of what? A vector of a `cdef class`, which I just told you that you can't do?

Comment: cdef class, i don't know how to reference PyObject